# Get_Pressed behaving oddly

Tags: python, pygame

I'm having some trouble with the keyboard events in my programme. Long story short I was using pygame.KEYDOWN events but then heard from pretty much everyone that get_pressed() is  a better suited option. I changed my code accordingly but have run into a few problems

Firstly:

If I am holding two keys but then only release one, pygame for some reason thinks that I have released both. This means that diagonal movement is a pain to implement

Secondly:

Diagonal movement IS working but only in certain cases when:

I'm moving up and down and hold left or right

It does not (for some reason) work if I'm going left or right and hold up or down

Here is the code I've been using:

```
while done == False:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        done = True
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if (keys[K_KP6]):
    square.spd_x+=5
    if square.spd_x > 5: # Put these speed limits in a function
        square.spd_x = 5
elif (keys[K_KP4]):
    square.spd_x -=5
    if square.spd_x <-5:
        square.spd_x = -5
elif (keys[K_KP8]):
    square.spd_y -=5
    if square.spd_y <-5:
        square.spd_y = -5
elif (keys[K_KP2]):
    square.spd_y +=5
    if square.spd_y >5:
        square.spd_y = 5
else:
    square.spd_x = 0
    square.spd_y = 0
```

If anyone could shed light on the issue I'd be extremely grateful and I thank you very much for attempting to answer

Thank you :D

Comment: I think the problem might be that you have elifs after everything, so it says: if up or down, then ignore left or right. It probably should be if up: moveup elif down:movedown else:setverticalmovementto0 if left:moveleft elif right:moveright else:sethorizontalmovementto0 so that it differentiates between horizontal and vertical movement. (oops just saw that pygamenerd said that first, my bad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will work, but it's worth a shot.

```
while done == False:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        done = True
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if (keys[K_KP6]):
    square.spd_x=5
else:
    square.spd_x=0
if (keys[K_KP4]):
    square.spd_x-=5
if (keys[K_KP8]):
    square.spd_y=-5
else:
    square.spd_y=0
if (keys[K_KP2]):
    square.spd_y +=5
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: That worked perfectly and even fixed some other issues I was having, thank you so much!